# parsing a xml string using xml.etree.ElementTree.fromstring in python

Tags: python, xml

I am new to python. I am trying to parse the xml data that i got as
a response from webpage. I am trying to use
[xml.etree.ElementTree.fromstring()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.fromstring) for the implementation.

My code is like:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
data = ET.fromstring(tables[x])
```

But here I am getting exception as `not well-formed (invalid token): line 4, column 1.`

The data `table[x]` is given below:

> [able](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/able)   adj. capable of performing; having an innate
>   capacity
>
> adept
>
> adequate
>
> [adroit](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/adroit)

I am trying to get output as: `adept  adequate adroit`

Please let me know how to work on it. Thanks in advance

Comment: Judging from the fact that SO seems to have formatted your table[x] as html, are you trying to parse HTML or XML?

Comment: data is in html format  <a href="http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/adept">
adept </a>
</li>
<li>
<a href="http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/adequate">
adequate </a>
</li>
<li>
<a href="http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/adroit">
adroit </a>
</li>

Comment: Ok.  I only mention because there are some HTML parsers (e.g. beautiful soup) which can make parsing HTML a bit easier in the long run.  However, lxml should work for parsing HTML.  The error you are getting is complaining that what it is receiving is not valid XML.  Can you do `print(str(tables[x]))` and let us know exactly what is getting passed into fromstring?  You can use the code tag in StackOverflow to display HTML without formatting it.

Comment: Thank you pace for your quick response. When I have try to print print(str(tables[x])), it is coming proper. Even I tried to pass whole html file to fromstring() and there also i got the same exception.

Comment: Are you getting EXACTLY what you posted in the question?  I ask because if I edit the question and look at the actual HTML I notice the tags go `<a>TEXT</a> </div>`  What is the div tag closing?  That is not valid XML because there is no opening `<div>`

Comment: Sorry being delayed. This is part of xml that i have posted.I have splitted the xml file using regular expression.Because this part contain the valid data. If I pass the whole xml file to that method, then also i got the same exception.

Comment: I can't tell you why it failed on the entire XML section without seeing the entire file but the section you are operating on right now is not valid XML cut out of the parent document like this.  It cannot be parsed with an XML parser.  If you need to split it up then parse the entire file and find and extract the section you want by navigating the resulting element tree, not by using regular expressions.  What error do you get when you try and parse the entire file?